# Issue with ActionBarActivityDelegate class.....app doesn't run

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-appcompat

Hello i hope someone can help me with his
I was planning to put an action bar in my test app, so I did exactly as said in the developers API guide.

But when i tried to compile it it throw this error (logcat):

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.createDelegate()
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate().....
..... 
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.<clinit>
```

What happens is that the app is correctly installed into my phone but even before it shows any UI, it throws the error and closes.

I even tried with the most simple app ("hello world example") and says the same thing
I tried it in both real phone and simulator, and same result

Any ideas how to fix that???? Seems that there is no definition for the class ActionBarActivityDelegateBase, but i cannot find any reference to that class in the guides or any other website

Comment: Have you installed the library project? It's not just the JAR.

Comment: I built the path and installed the library, but still the same..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had that error, and the problem was that I hadn't added the lib with the resources.
You can't just add the jars, because it will not add the resources. You have to create a project from thoses libs and then add the project as a library to your own project.

Here's the instructions how to:

Go to this link and go to the "Adding libraries with resources" section

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

This fixed the problem for me.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue about 20 minutes ago.  I fixed it in the Manifest by changing the theme from "AppTheme" to "Theme.AppCompat"

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
```

Comment: When I try to change it to Theme.AppCompat it says that eclipse didn't find the resource.....did you created a new style resource with that name or it is included in the supportv7 package ?

Comment: It's included, I was just going by what I read here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html in the section titled "Adding the Action Bar"

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Android-Studio 1.0.2 and I had the same problem. I fixed the issue removing `compile 'com.google.android.gms'` from build.gradle. Not too sure about the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a whole day trying to fix this. I am using eclipse on debian. I ended up adding the library android-support-v7-appcompt and my app into one working set and built the "working set" to resolve the issue. This eventually created the necessary files in android-support-v7-appcompat/bin folder.