# ActionBarActivity requestFeature must be called before adding content

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbaractivity

**Edit reflecting `matias's` comments**

Actually, originally I had no `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` or `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` in my code until I noticed the `runtime exception when below combinations of actions happened`

> User presses **Home** button to minimize the application and tried to resume it from **Recent Apps** (*which is long press of the home button*)
>
> When Screen rotation occurs (Note: The manifest **does not have** *configChange* declarations)

Then i thought showing indeterminate progress bar during initialization should be causing the issue, so only i tried calling `request*` methods , thinking it will clear it off, but nothing happened..

> Finally i removed `showPdIndeterminate();` for the sake of testing. Hence nowhere in my code i am showing it. Still the same happens during the aforementioned circumstances

---

I have a fragment based `ActionBarActivity`, my layout is wrapped inside `DrawerLayout` with `two framelayouts` to hold two frgaments.

I tried [requestFeature() must be called before adding content error on super.onCreate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205426/requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-content-error-on-super-oncreate) but still same exception for

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Inside OnCreate");
    // supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    showPdIndeterminate();
           ....
}
```

and `showPdIndeterminate()` is

```
private void showPdIndeterminate() {
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Initializing", "Pls wait...");
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    pd.show();
}
```

I am getting `NullPointerException` if I try `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);`, so only commented it.

The error log is:

```
06-16 04:04:57.280: D/AndroidRuntime(27280): Shutting down VM
06-16 04:04:57.280: W/dalvikvm(27280): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413592a0)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.demo/com.example.demo.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3553)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1233)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:267)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3320)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:63)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at com.example.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:464)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
06-16 04:04:57.285: E/AndroidRuntime(27280):    ... 12 more
```

Note: **I am getting this exception on orientation change as well as when i launch it from recent applications list by pressing home button**

> **This exception is **eventually** arising regrdless of having (not having)  `setRetainInstance(true);`  in fragment's `onActivityCreated() or`onCreate()`**

Why is this happening? How to solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No FEATURE\_INDETERMINATE\_PROGRESS in ActionBarCompat for Android 2.3-](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027603/no-feature-indeterminate-progress-in-actionbarcompat-for-android-2-3)

Comment: Per the duplicate: use [ActionBarActivity.supportRequestWindowFeature](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#supportRequestWindowFeature(int))

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin, posted error log

Comment: @ianhanniballake, if it's duplicate as you mentioned, i don't find the solution from the suggested link, ca you post an answer from that link

Comment: @nmxprime is it going good without Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS?

Comment: @nmxprime for the first error type, are you willing to lock your app's orientation (horizontal or vertical)?

Comment: @nmxprime are you using android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity?

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest, I am using ` android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`. I am not about to lock the orienttion

Comment: @nmxprime Exactly why are you trying to call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)`? That is necessary only if you intend to use `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility()`. You do not need it if you just need to show a `ProgressDialog`.

Comment: @matiash yes I want to show an indeterminate progress bar

Comment: @nmxprime I don't understand. One thing is showing an indeterminate `ProgressDialog` (as you're doing here in `showPdIndeterminate()`. That does **not** require calling `requestWindowFeature()` at all. Another, completely different thing, is using `Activity.setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility()` (which you're not doing). If this code you pasted is what you intend t do, you can remove `requestWindowFeature()` and it should work fine.

Comment: @matiash, Actually i had the issue when i was not calling any of the `request*` methods; on getting this error only i tried to call `those request*` methods. I will try your suggestions and update you soon

Comment: @matiash, using `supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);` and `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true)` together not working, same error. Also calling either independently also esulted in same exception

Comment: @matiash, Please see the edits

Comment: @nmxprime What I meant was: call _none_ of them. They are not needed in this case.

Comment: @matiash, the same for not calling case also...

Comment: @nmxprime Hello I have same probem with screen orietation did you solve it?

Comment: @Sultan, At first the solution was removing progress dialog. But that seemed not to be the solution, rather just a local fix. NOwadays I am using similar situations, where the problem is not occuring. It may possibly be support library bug. Try updating your support library. If using `ActionBarActivitym FragmentActivity, etc.,` just ensure the same happens with `Activity` !

Comment: but I dont use any progress dialog in my case and I have latest supp. library can you look throw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404146/when-orientation-changed-i-got-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-con

Answer (score 1):

Override `setContentView` in your Activity and see where / what is calling the method. Once you find out what is calling it, I'm sure we can figure out a workable solution.

```
@Override
public void setContentView (int layoutResID)
{
  //Set a break point on the next line or log out a message. 
  super.setContentView(layoutResID);
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest any way how to override it, because i don't know what else do there?

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the author may be calling setContentView in an unexpected way (or has something else calling it). If that is this case, the answer is him simply finding that out (which is why I proposed my solution).

Comment: Justin, if you read my comment again,  `what else` it would imply `what else to do other than calling it's super method...`

Comment: If you read the comment I left in the example, you should set a breakpoint there. Once you do that, you can look at the stack trace of the call and see who is calling setContentView before your requestWindowFeature call

Comment: Thanks Justin let me try it

Answer (score 0):

The `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` changes a window's content by adding an `ActionBar`. Furthermore the `FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS` depends on whether an action bar is present or not.

Try something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   ABD = ActionBarActivityDelegate.createDelegate(this);
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   ABD.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

The `ActionBarActivityDelegate` class can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivityDelegate.java).

Lastly, you should look into locking your screens orientation if possible. This is described in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675750/lock-screen-orientation-android).

Comment: You're referring ActionBarDelegae, which is not in the `android.support.v7` library I am using (I am sure not using out-dated library)

Comment: Actually The app have to support orientaton change

Comment: @nmxprime did you look at the link I provided for the ActionBarActivityDelegate?? its part of suppourt v7 for sure

Comment: its available as of 4.4.2_r1. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivityDelegate.java/

Comment: and i am getting it reported in android 4.1.2

Comment: Yes it is available in 4.1.2. Did you try the above code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56991/discussion-between-nmxprime-and-seahawksrdabest).

Comment: @nmxprime did you add the new library to your project?

Comment: I have no doubt that i am using latest library, and this `android.support.v7.app` contains no `ActionBarDelegate` to use. If your support library has this, can you send it to me?

Comment: have you added it as a support library TO YOUR PROJRCT?(different then just adding just the .jar file) .Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890589/issue-with-actionbaractivitydelegate-class-app-doesnt-run

Comment: I am using the Templates which adds it automatically, do you recommend manually as listed in Android's develper's site?

Comment: Yes. Just having the library doesn't mean your project knows it has to use it. Follow the steps on the android website to add a reference library to your project.

Comment: `ActionBarActivityDelegate` is not public.

Comment: can you help in my case this is not worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404146/when-orientation-changed-i-got-requestfeature-must-be-called-before-adding-con

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `requestWindowFeature()` before `setcontentView()` but after `onCreate()`.

Works for me.